# SQL String split and update field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table `Project` with a column name `Name` with values in the format `SYS_12345_Value`. I want to update this `Name` field such that its value in every row is replaced by the term after **second** `_` in its value.

At the moment it looks like `SYS_82058_INDIGO` and I want to replace it with `INDIGO` and the same for all the rows in the table.

[image]

Any help is appreciated. Thanks alot.

UPDATE : Tried @GordonLinoff's solution as follows

```
UPDATE Project
SET Name = (select right(str, charindex('_', reverse(str)) - 1) from (values (Name)) v(str))
WHERE Name like '%SYS%'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String manipulation in SQL Server is usually tricky.  But if you want the *last* component, you can use:

```
select *,
       right(str, charindex('_', reverse(str)) - 1)
from (values ('SYS_82058_INDIGO')) v(str)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a couple of nested `CHARINDEX` functions. This assumes that every row has 2 underscore (`_`) characters:

```sql
UPDATE dbo.YourTable
SET YourColumn = STUFF(YourColumn,1,CHARINDEX('_',YourColumn,CHARINDEX('_',YourColumn)+1),'');
```